# Swap multi line in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have problem In swap multi line it only swap one line?

```
Dim st As String=TextBox1.Text
st=String.Join(":", st.Split(":"). Reverse())
TextBox1.Text =st
```

[image: prj]

[proj1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAw9e.jpg)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What was the input?  What was the output?  What output did you expect?  Why?

Comment: i added two image of my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Lines collection of the text box to operate on each line individually. I used a string builder to create the new text of the text box. When ever you change a string the compiler creates an entirely new string. A `StringBuilder` avoids some of this overhead.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each line As String In TextBox1.Lines
        sb.AppendLine(String.Join(":", line.Split(":"c).Reverse()))
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Imports System.Text` at the top of your Form code file along with the other Imports